# R data.table - alternative to lapply?

Tags: r, data.table

I am working on a sales dataset and I need to restructure a data.table that looks like:

```
ID sales month
23 657   01
67 889   01
.
.
.
23 238   12
```

to the following format:

```
ID 01  02  03  ... 12
23 657 445 223 ... 238
67 889 990 765 ... 555
.
.
.
```

The code I currently have supplies a list of all unique IDs to lapply and the function gets all rows with the matching ID, creates a data table with one row, and joins it to the main restructured table using rbindlist.

This works for a small number of unique IDs (~600), but when the number of IDs is large, it's very slow and not feasible. Is there a more efficient way to do this? (A data.table specific approach?)

Comment: You are trying to reshape the data. Check this `data.table` answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36253517

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(Df1), ID ~ month, value.var = 'sales')
```

Comment: dcast is great, it restructured ~70k IDs instantly. Thank you for the answer.